# How to seed dummy data to a mongoose database when user password confirmation is in place

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I need to seed some dummy user info to a mongoose database, the user model checks for password confirmation when a real user submits the form online, this needs to stay in place. I am running mongod and also using gulp in my terminal but I get the ValidatorError each time I run my seeds file with Node. Can anyone advise how to get by this issue.

User Model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt   = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  postcode: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});

userSchema.pre('save', function hashPassword(next) {
  if (this.isModified('password')) {
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8));
  }
  next();
});

userSchema
  .virtual('passwordConfirmation')
  .set(function setPasswordConfirmation(passwordConfirmation) {
    this._passwordConfirmation = passwordConfirmation;
  });

userSchema.pre('validate', function checkPassword(next) {
  if (this.isModified('password') && this._passwordConfirmation !== this.password) this.invalidate('passwordConfirmation', 'does not match');
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.validatePassword = function validatePassword(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Seeds file.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { port, db, secret }    = require('../config/env');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect(db);

const User = require('../models/user');
const Event = require('../models/event');

User.collection.drop();
Event.collection.drop();

User.create([{
  username: 'dan123',
  email: 'dan@dan.com',
  postcode: 'SE270JF',
  password: '123'
}, {
  username: 'ben123',
  email: 'ben@ben.com',
  postcode: 'SE191SB',
  password: '123'
}])
.then(user => {
  console.log(`${user.length} users created`);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
.finally(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

I have to use my current package setup so can not apply advice outside this scope. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you created a validation that require you to supply `passwordConfirmation` that match the `password` on the creation process.

You can live with that by adding the `passwordConfirmation` field to your seed data:

```js
User.create([{
  username: 'dan123',
  email: 'dan@dan.com',
  postcode: 'SE270JF',
  password: '123'
  passwordConfirmation: '123',
}, {
  username: 'ben123',
  email: 'ben@ben.com',
  postcode: 'SE191SB',
  password: '123',
  passwordConfirmation: '123',
}])
```